# How to use deferred object to store result and serve it from local memory next time?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, jquery-deferred

I want to get the mustache template from server and store it locally for later use.

I'm using $.get to have promise-like behaviour in my code, but how after first call, can I store the result for later use and use this stored code instead another server call?

What i have now:

```
...

getTemplate() {
    return $.get(this.templateUrl);
}

...

this.getTemplate().then((template) => {}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store it in a local variable?:

```
getTemplate() {
  if(this._cached)
    return this._cached;

  return this._cached = $.get(this.templateUrl);
}
```

The rest should be done with the browser's [caching](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/http-caching?hl=en)